# Django aggregation and queries

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a number of elements that can be of one or more types.

```
class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

class Element(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    type = models.ManyToManyField('Type')
```

Let's say that I have 3 types and 3 elements:

```
In [3]: Type.objects.all()
Out[3]: [<Type: His Type>, <Type: My Type>, <Type: Your Type>]

In [4]: [(e,e.type.all()) for e in Element.objects.all()]
Out[4]: 
[(<Element: First Element>, [<Type: My Type>]),
(<Element: Second Element>, [<Type: Your Type>]),
(<Element: Third Element>,
  [<Type: My Type>, <Type: Your Type>, <Type: His Type>])]
```

I'm trying to get a queryset with the elements that are only of the type "My Type"

My idea was to get the elements of this type and check that they are only of one type.

But for some reason it thinks that "Third Element" is of only one type

```
In [5]: my_type=Type.objects.get(name='My Type')

In [6]: my_type.element_set.annotate(num_types=Count('type')).filter(num_types__exact=1)
Out[6]: [<Element: First Element>, <Element: Third Element>]

In [7]: [(e,e.num_types) for e in my_type.element_set.annotate(num_types=Count('type'))]
Out[7]: [(<Element: First Element>, 1), (<Element: Third Element>, 1)]
```

when it is of three types

```
In [8]: Element.objects.get(name='Third Element').type.count()
Out[8]: 3
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended doing

`Element.objects.filter(pk__in=my_type.element_set.values_list('pk', flat=True)).annotate(num_types=Count('type')).filter(num_types=1)`

That way I'm not affected by the join that happens when I start with `my_type.element_set`

If you are wondering about the SQL involved:

In `my_type.element_set.annotate(num_types=Count('type')).filter(num_types__exact=1)` it does:

```
SELECT `senalesweb_element`.`id`, `senalesweb_element`.`name`, COUNT(`senalesweb_element_type`.`type_id`) AS `num_types` FROM `senalesweb_element` LEFT OUTER JOIN `senalesweb_element_type` ON (`senalesweb_element`.`id` = `senalesweb_element_type`.`element_id`) WHERE (`senalesweb_element_type`.`type_id` = 1 ) GROUP BY `senalesweb_element`.`id` HAVING COUNT(`senalesweb_element_type`.`type_id`) = 1  ORDER BY NULL LIMIT 21
```

While in `Element.objects.filter(pk__in=my_type.element_set.values_list('pk', flat=True)).annotate(num_types=Count('type')).filter(num_types=1)` it does:

```
SELECT `senalesweb_element`.`id`, `senalesweb_element`.`name`, COUNT(`senalesweb_element_type`.`type_id`) AS `num_types` FROM `senalesweb_element` LEFT OUTER JOIN `senalesweb_element_type` ON (`senalesweb_element`.`id` = `senalesweb_element_type`.`element_id`) WHERE (`senalesweb_element`.`id` IN (SELECT U0.`id` FROM `senalesweb_element` U0 INNER JOIN `senalesweb_element_type` U1 ON (U0.`id` = U1.`element_id`) WHERE U1.`type_id` = 1 )) GROUP BY `senalesweb_element`.`id` HAVING COUNT(`senalesweb_element_type`.`type_id`) = 1  ORDER BY NULL LIMIT 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is a standard many-to-many, you can call 'my_type.element_set.all()', that should give you the Element instances that are of that type. You can also go the other way (using pluralized version of model name, not '_set') to get an elements types like so: 'my_element.types.all()'.

To get the count, just do 'my_type.element_set.count()'.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query that Django is performing behind the scenes is limiting you to only the rows that contain `type_element_type.element_id = 1`.  So the annotated count is only applying to those, hence 1 each.

Your query [7] above becomes this SQL (as shown by [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running)):

```
SELECT "type_element"."id", "type_element"."name", COUNT("type_element_type"."type_id") 
AS "num_types" FROM "type_element" LEFT OUTER JOIN "type_element_type"
ON ("type_element"."id" = "type_element_type"."element_id")
WHERE "type_element_type"."type_id" = 1 
GROUP BY "type_element"."id", "type_element"."name"
```

and from sqlite3:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM "type_element" LEFT OUTER JOIN "type_element_type" ON ("type_element"."id" = "type_element_type"."element_id") WHERE "type_element_type"."type_id" = 1;
1|First Element|1|1|1
3|Third Element|3|3|1
```

Comment: I guessed that the cause was the join, but I was asking about a way to rewrite the query. In the end I found a solution.